# No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to build my app but can't it always gives me problems with FirebaseFirestore.

It seems to recognize FirebaseStorage and Firebase fine but not FireStore.

Here are the images with problems and some code:

[image: error]

Code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore //No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'    
var docRefIm: DocumentReference!
var docRefImC: CollectionReference!

class carregar: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var upload: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func uploadBt(_ sender: Any) {

        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.allowsEditing = true
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present(image, animated: true){

        }
    }
```

I tried deleting and reinstalling the pods, deleting the modules, adding the schemes, and nothing seems to work.

Here is the pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, ’8.0’

target 'MarisaeRui' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MarisaeRui
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  target 'MarisaeRuiTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

  target 'MarisaeRuiUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

end
```

[image: pod install]

Comment: Can you post your Podfile ?

Comment: i actually was about to do it XD

Comment: can you un-comment the platform line be removing the # and then install the pods again

Comment: already tried it, nothing changed

Comment: it was working at some time, than I had to do pod deintegrate to fix something and never worked since

Comment: well it says that it you should backup you project before doing so. you can try to delete the workspace file and then install the pods again to regenerate it

Comment: tried over 10 times.
even tried starting a new project from scratch and I get the same problem

Comment: From the first screenshot, it looks like the root problem is FirebaseFirestore failing to build in your environment. What's your Xcode version?

Comment: im using xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok, sorry. Just did because its a surprise for someone for 2days from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with using Firestore on Xcode 8.3.3.

The easiest workaround would be to move to Xcode 9 - which will be [required this month for submissions to the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/).

Alternatively, you could fix the build error in the Firestore sources. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1517) for more details.

Comment: I'm using a mac from a friend that as the SierraOs and can't install xcode 9

Comment: I've fixed this in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/1519, which includes a new Travis CI configuration to verify we don't break this in the future. You can now temporarily work around this by pulling the FirebaseFirestore pod from master. See instructions here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/README.md for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add or uncomment this command

> use_frameworks!

This should be below project name like this

```
target 'Project-Name' do
use_frameworks!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your PODs...

pod 'FirebaseCore', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :branch => 'master'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :branch => 'master'